# How to instantiate object of class B from show.html of class A in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

The class 'sessions' belongs_to class_users. A 'session' may have_many 'distractions'.

I'd like to be able to instantiate a 'distraction' object from the show view of the distraction class with the click of a button. How do I do this?

TO CLARIFY:
I know reloading the page is necessary since I'm not using AJAX. That's ok. I just want the show page to reload after the user clicks the button and reflect the newly instantiated 'distraction' object.

**Session Model**

```
class Session < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :distractions, dependent: :destroy
    validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**Distraction Model**

```
class Distraction < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :session
end
```

**SessionsController**

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_session,:authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show], only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @sessions = current_user.sessions
    end

    def show
        @session = Session.find(params[:id])
    end

    def new
        @session = current_user.Session.build
    end

    def edit
        @session
    end

  def new_distraction
    @distraction = Distraction.create
  end

    def create
    @session = current_user.sessions.build(session_params)

    if @session.update(session_params)
      redirect_to @session, notice: 'Session was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @session.ended_at = Time.now

    if @session.save
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Session was successfully ended.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @session.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to root_path }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_session
    @session = Session.find(params[:id])
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def session_params
    params.require(:session).permit(:name, :ended_at)
  end

end
```

**DistractionsController**

```
class DistractionsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @distractions = current_session.Distraction.all
    end

    def new
        @distraction = Distraction.new
    end

    def create
        @distraction = Distraction.build
        if @distraction.save
            redirect_to '/sessions/show', notice: "Distraction saved successfully."
        else
            redirect_to '/sessions/show', notice: "Distraction could not be saved!"

        end
    end

end
```

**Views/sessions/show**

```
<h1><%= @session.name %></h1>

<%= render './distractions/form' %>

<br>

<p>

You have been distracted
<%= @session.distractions.size %>
 times.

</p>

<%= button_to 'End Session', session_path(@session, ended_at: Time.now) %>
```

**views/distractions/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= button_to 'One Distraction', action: 'create' %>
```

I've been struggling with this but continue to get a variety of routing errors etc. Here's my config/routing.rb:

```
Distracker::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :distractions
  resources :sessions
  devise_for :users do get '/users/sign_out' => 'devise/sessions#destroy' end
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
   root 'pages#home'

  # Example of regular route:
  #   get 'products/:id' => 'catalog#view'

  # Example of named route that can be invoked with purchase_url(id: product.id)
  #   get 'products/:id/purchase' => 'catalog#purchase', as: :purchase

  # Example resource route (maps HTTP verbs to controller actions automatically):
  #   resources :products

  # Example resource route with options:
  #   resources :products do
  #     member do
  #       get 'short'
  #       post 'toggle'
  #     end
  #
  #     collection do
  #       get 'sold'
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments, :sales
  #     resource :seller
  #   end

  # Example resource route with more complex sub-resources:
  #   resources :products do
  #     resources :comments
  #     resources :sales do
  #       get 'recent', on: :collection
  #     end
  #   end

  # Example resource route with concerns:
  #   concern :toggleable do
  #     post 'toggle'
  #   end
  #   resources :posts, concerns: :toggleable
  #   resources :photos, concerns: :toggleable

  # Example resource route within a namespace:
  #   namespace :admin do
  #     # Directs /admin/products/* to Admin::ProductsController
  #     # (app/controllers/admin/products_controller.rb)
  #     resources :products
  #   end
end
```

Finally, in case I missed something relevant, here is the github repo:

https://github.com/justuseapen/distraction

Comment: Technically you can't. Ruby is a server side language. Once it has been sent to the client, Ruby can no longer execute code. You can use AJAX in order to make Ruby execute more code. What are you attempting to do? There may be a better way of accomplishing your task.

Comment: User clicks the button, page reloads and reflects newly instantiated 'distraction' object. I gave up on trying to do this through ajax and figured this should be simple but I can't figure it out.

Comment: When you say newly instantiated, do you mean you just want to show a new random distraction object?

Comment: No, I have a sessions.distractions.size call that counts the amount of distractions associated with the session. Really distraction is just a tally marker. Clicking the button should make the object and reload the page with the updated count.

Comment: can you post the error messages you are getting?

Comment: currently I'm getting this:

ActionController::ParameterMissing - param not found: session:

but, trying different things yields different errors.